# Easiest way to store alphabet in dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to store the alphabet in a Dictionary. I have followed the below steps to do so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] c = "ABCDFFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    int key = 1;
    Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    foreach (char value in c)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value.ToString());
        key++;
    }
}
```

I don't want to first store the alphabet in an array and then in a dictionary. Is any other way to implement my requirement?

Comment: Sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you `have an requirement to store alphabets in Dictionary`? What is the end goal?

Comment: Why do I constantly see people using `ToCharArray` before a `foreach`? Strings are already a sequence of chars. You don't have to turn them into arrays first.  Is there some tutorial or something that is saying to do this? You could have just said `foreach(char c in "ABCDEFG")`

Comment: If the purpose of the dictionary is to find the nth letter of alphabet, simply use `(char)('A' - 1 + n)` for upper-case and `(char)('a' - 1 + n)` for lower-case. No dictionary needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    int key = c - 'A' + 1;
    dictionary.Add(key, c.ToString());
}
```

Char is actually a numeric type, so you can use it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

char and int are interchangeable and you can just do this

Dictionary dictionary = new Dictionary();

```
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
            dictionary[c - 64] = c.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to first store the alphabet in an array and then in a dictionary.

Then just Initialize your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> alphabet= new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1, "A" },
    { 2, "B" },
    { 3, "C" } // etc
};
```

If you wanted to do it dynamically with ASCII, I'd probably do:

```
var values = Enumerable
    // Returns values 65 to 92 (I think 92) 
    .Range((int)'A', (int)'Z' - (int)'A')
    // Select that can automatically give me the index of each value
    .Select((Val, Index) => new { Index, Val })
    // Creates a dictionary...
    .ToDictionary((iv) => iv.Index, (iv) => iv.Val.Tostring());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you don't want to use an array, but it's possible to use ASCII

Use the key 65 - 64 (which will be equal to 1) and for letter `(char) 65` A.

Run this from i = 65 (A) to i = 90 (Z)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a collection initializer on the Dictionary object:

```
var i = 0;
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {++i, "A"},
    {++i, "B" }
    // etc.
};
```